# QMainWindow file not found

Tags: c++, qt

I created new project in QtCreator version 7.
in mainwindow.h there is an error QMainWindow file not found.
I tried it on Qt6 and Qt5 and each has this trouble.
Searched the web - all fine

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the relevant parts of your code. You need to present a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Are you using cmake or qmake?

Comment: Problem was in cyrillic symbols in my Windows username
Ran it in C:\ fixed